# Uplay crashing on logging in

Tags: ubisoft-connect

I'm trying to play Watchdogs, however, EVERY time I try and open Uplay it crashed, I've tried reinstalling, restarting my PC, restartinig my PC between each step of reinstalling Uplay and everytime it crashed on logging in. Is this a current bug or is this actually fixable?

Here's a screenshot of the dump file[image]

Comment: I've had this recently too when I tried to get The Mighty Quest For Epic Loot working ... I recall fixing my problem after browsing a number of forum posts. I'll see if I can find the post again.

Comment: I remember the UPlay uninstaller being really sloppy, can you check that it left no files behind in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher? I would try reinstalling and then restarting your computer after that. Pending a better answer ...

Comment: From what I understand, UPlay was breaking today.  Perhaps it doesn't know how to fail gracefully, and it just up and dies on you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I found on the Steam forum, it seems to be working for quite a few people:

> - I uninstalled Uplay entirely. ***It leaves files behind! Go to your \program files (x86)\ folder and delete the Ubisoft folder there completely. This was necessary for me to do***
> - I restarted my computer (had to do this too, no restart after removal/installation did nothing for me before)
> - I re-installed Uplay using the installer found on Uplay's website.
> - After installation, I restarted again.
> - I launched the game through Steam and after about a minute, Uplay finally came up without crashing and updated itself.
> - Exit Uplay.
> - Re-launch the game through Steam again, and now you can input your key to activate it.

UPDATE: I just used this method to use uPlay, and it worked! Just a quick note, when you first launch the game through Steam it will say it is installing uPlay. Just let it run, and it will end up launching and likely will not need to update itself

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/235600/discussions/0/846962439208487864/#c846962439210271067)

Comment: Do you have a link to this?  Attribution is important (and ensures we know who did what).

Comment: Here is a link to the full forum, the comment I got the solution from is on this page

http://steamcommunity.com/app/235600/discussions/0/846962439208487864/

Comment: @Adam Couldp you edit that in?

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: @peper757 there should be a source button towards the bottom of my original post, click that and it should take you to the Steam forum

Comment: @Adam It's fine now, it's just been edited in.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work, but then randomly about 15 tries later Uplay worked, so maybe it was an issue on there end what they sorted. Seeing as this has been the most useful bit of advice I've found I'll make it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/48220/discussions/0/619574421469882244/?insideModal=1#c619574421472422618), there's an even easier solution that doesn't require you to [uninstall UPlay and restart your machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/169505/90128):

> Try:
>
> Go in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher" then
>   right click on "Uplay.exe" and lauch as admin, and compatibility
>   Windows 7 (I'm running Win 8)
>
> Start Uplay with the changed settings and log in

You'll then need to login to UPlay and activate your game with its game key.